# back to result page?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is my url structure: (landing pages)

```
/locale/villas/ 
Listing of all the villas with url's pointing to the country and region. Examples: 

/locale/italy/tuscany/villas/villa-r
/locale/italy/tuscany/villas/villa-t
/locale/italy/umbria/villas/villa-u
/locale/spain/andalusia/villas/villa-a
etc...

/locale/country/villas/ 
Listing of the villas in the specified country with url's pointing to the country and region. Examples: 

/locale/italy/tuscany/villas/villa-x
/locale/italy/tuscany/villas/villa-y
/locale/italy/umbria/villas/villa-z
etc...

/locale/country/region/villas/ 
Listing of the villas in the specified country and region with url's pointing to the country and region. Examples: 

/locale/italy/tuscany/villas/villa-x
/locale/italy/tuscany/villas/villa-y
/locale/italy/umbria/villas/villa-z
etc...
```

When a visitor visits the landing page `/locale/villas` and clicks on the a villas it goes 
`/locale/italy/tuscany/villas/villa-x` (villa-x has multiple pages), and they are in the "tuscany enviroment".

Now I want to make a button with "go back to the search results" so they go back to the initial `/listing` page. How can I do that? `:back` is not a option because the villa has multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use caching for this. Because cache object is also available on controller as well as on view.

You should set url in cache object from view and will redirect from controller on that particular link.